# Is there a name for a basketball screen on the baseline for a shooter running away from the basket?

Tags: basketball, terminology

In basketball, if you have a screen angled towards the baseline, with the shooter using the screen running up from the baseline, you call that a "pindown". If you have a screen around the top of the key for a shooter running parallel to the baseline out to the slot, you call that a "flare screen". But is there a standard name for a screen on the baseline for a shooter running parallel to the baseline, away from the basket (often to take a baseline jumper)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In @jros's [answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/28032/24063), they link an article from [BasketballForCoaches.com](https://www.basketballforcoaches.com/basketball-screens/) where it defines a flare screen as

> an off-ball screen that allows a player to cut away from the basketball to a spot somewhere around the perimeter

This fits the situation described, except on the baseline. So I think it would be reasonable to call this kind of screen a "baseline flare screen"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to a **Flex Screen** here, which is when that baseline screen is set on the the baseline, usually the opposite side of the floor from the ball, and the recipient cuts along the baseline off the screen (see #10 on this article from [BasketballForCoaches.com](https://www.basketballforcoaches.com/basketball-screens/)). You can also see some common names for many common screen tactics on that page.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like that's a screen for a player cutting towards the basket. I meant for a player cutting away from the basket, often for a jump shot (I've edited to try to make that clearer). I was watching Bucks vs Pacers 2000 and both teams were running this play a fair bit, but you don't see it so much any more

Comment: Though according to the article you posted, maybe you'd call what I'm describing a flare screen, just on the baseline